# Twisted Python - In deferred's callback's function call, raised exception not displayed in stdout

Tags: python, exception, twisted

**Test Setup**

I have an asynchronous Twisted HTTP server for handling POST:

```
class HttpResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = True;
    def render_POST(self, request):
        ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    factory = Site(HttpResource())
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

I created a simple test() function that raises an exception:

```
def test():
    print "test() called"
    raise Exception("Exception raised!")
```

**Capturing Exception message (i.e. "Exception raised!") in program output**

If I call test() within render_POST(), the exception is raised and output shows the message as expected:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise Exception("Exception!")
exceptions.Exception: Exception!
```

However, if within render_POST() I create a deferred pointing to a callback that executes test(), the exception is presumably still raised (client gets a 500 internal server error) but no exception error message (the "Exception raised!" phrase) is shown.

**Question**

How can I get Exception error messages to show when they arise from function calls within a callback?

**UPDATE 1: Demo code provided (requires Twisted for server.py)**    
**UPDATE 2: Demo code returns "NOT_DONE_YET"

client.py

```
import json, urllib2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input("Enter cmd number (1, 2, or 0): ")
        if cmd == str(1):
            raw_data = {'cmd' : 'cmd1'}
        elif cmd == str(2):
            raw_data = {'cmd' : 'cmd2'}
        elif cmd == str(0):
            break;
        req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8000')
        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(raw_data))
        print response.read()
```

server.py

```
import json, time
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site, NOT_DONE_YET

def test():
    print "test() called"
    time.sleep(1)
    raise Exception("Exception raised!")

def callback(result):
    print "callback() called"
    test()

class HttpResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = True;
    def render_POST(self, request):
        msg = json.loads(request.content.getvalue())
        if msg['cmd'] == 'cmd1': # call test() directly
            test()
        elif msg['cmd'] == 'cmd2': # call test() from callback
            d = getPage('http://www.yahoo.com')
            d.addCallbacks(callback, callback)

        return NOT_DONE_YET

if __name__ == "__main__":
    factory = Site(HttpResource())
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Please include a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct Example"](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates this problem.  I appreciate that you've tried to be thorough in your description, but since I can't run your exact code, I don't know exactly what your problem might be.

Comment: @Glyph Thanks for the advice. Working code is now attached.

Comment: I have tried your example, and it does print out "callback() called" for me.
Also, there is no technical reason why Deferred should behave differently to direct calls with regards to prints.
Maybe it's worth adding a different type of side-effect in the callback function to see if it gets invoked at all; you might have a more basic problem.

Comment: @RomanK It is expected that "callback() called" is shown--that print statement is to prove that callback() is indeed called. The problem is what follows. Callback() should (and does, as evidenced by another print stmt) call test(). Test() should show the exception message in output, but doesn't. This is the issue I'm troubled with.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that test() was also called and printing out for me.

Comment: @RomanK but does the exception error message ("Exception raised!") print after "test() called"?

Comment: @Aaron - it is printed, though as a part of the exception stack, since you do not handle the exception (see also Glyph's response).

Here is my output copy/pasted with some of the call stack suppressed (I guess comment is not the best place for it, but I don't think I have the right to claim an answer):

callback() called
test() called
Unhandled error in Deferred:

  File "server.py", line 14, in callback
    test()
  File "server.py", line 10, in test
    raise Exception("Exception raised!")
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>: Exception raised!

Comment: @RomanK So you *are* getting output in the exception stack when using "cmd2"? For some reason, I am not. My output is "callback() called test() called"...nothing else. Do you know why?

Comment: @Aaron - Yes, I do get the exception stack. My educated guess is that we have different versions of Twisted, and yours suppresses call stacks in `twisted.web.resource.Resource` classes.

The reason I suspect that is that my build of Twisted is quite old, and sounds like a reasonable behaviour adjustment in later Twisted versions. Perhaps you might want to catch the exception at the point where you raise it, and print it there to confirm this suspicion?

Comment: @RomanK Thanks RomanK for your input. I followed Glyph's recommendation to use Klein, which helps output exceptions perfectly. It is easy to setup and works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here relevant to your missing traceback.

The first problem with your program is that when you return `None` from `render_POST`, this tells twisted.web that you are done handling the request and that the connection should be closed immediately.  By the time your callback gets around to pushing some data out to the HTTP channel, the response has already been sent and the data is discarded.

The second problem is that you are never actually pushing data out to the connection at all.  When render_POST itself raises an exception, the code calling it can catch that exception.  However, the code calling `render_POST` doesn't expect a `Deferred`, and even if it did, you're not returning one here.

There is also a third problem, which is that you're using `time.sleep` which freezes your whole program rather than `deferLater` which would return a `Deferred` that simply fires at a later time and allows concurrent tasks to proceed.  Since the `time.sleep` is entirely beside the point though, and the behavior is the same whether you include it or not, we can ignore it :-).

There is a way to address this problem within Twisted itself, but an easier way to address it would be to use [Klein](http://klein.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which handles `Deferred` for you automatically.

Using Klein, your example would be:

```
import json

from klein import run, route
from twisted.web.client import getPage

def test():
    print "test() called"
    raise Exception("Exception raised!")

def callback(result):
    print "callback() called"
    test()

@route("/", methods=["POST"])
def example(request):
    msg = json.loads(request.content.getvalue())
    if msg['cmd'] == 'cmd1': # call test() directly
        test()
    elif msg['cmd'] == 'cmd2': # call test() from callback
        d = getPage('http://www.yahoo.com')
        return d.addCallbacks(callback, callback)

run("localhost", 8000)
```

Note the **`return d.addCallbacks`**; if you don't `return` the result it will continue failing in more or less the same way it does now.

Comment: I should've given better demo code. My real code returns NOT_DONE_YET and doesn't use time.sleep :) If I'm understanding (and quoting) you correctly, "there is a way to address this problem within Twisted itself"...could you show me how?

Comment: You've corrected it to use `NOT_DONE_YET`, but it is still calling time.sleep :).  Please post your *actual* code (perhaps in a new question so I can provide a separate answer).